# how to update a function on server side but keep the one on client side unchanged

Tags: client-server

**Server side:**

```
function sender(x, y){
   do something
}
```

**Client side:**

```
function receiver(x,y){
   do something
}
```

Now, somehow we need to change the function on server side to only need one parameter:

```
function sender(x){
   do something
}
```

Without changing/updating the function on client side, how can we keep these two functions working with each other?

Comment: can you explain it more?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to make a wrapper for the new function. like this:
function sender(x,y) {sender(x)}